# Derivative of the norm of a Quaternion in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, quaternions, derivative

I am rather new to Mathematica and am using it to work on Quaternions at the moment. In one particular case I would like to obtain a derivative involving the norm of a Quaternion, like the following:

```
In[1]:= << Quaternions`

D[Norm[Quaternion[a, b, c, d]], b]
                                                (0,1,0,0)
Out[6]= Norm'[Quaternion[a, b, c, d]] Quaternion         [a, b, c, d]
```

Mathematica is actually capable of computing the Norm of a Quaternion but does someone know whether it can expand the Norm function so that the above input yields the expanded derivative (//FunctionExpand did not change anything on the output...).

Any hints are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The functions in the Quaternions' package won't recognize  symbolic arguments, and their Norm definition doesn't conform to Mathworld's anyway.

Comment: This probably settles it then, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Norm of a quaternion is simply Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2]. So, any one of the partial derivatives can be determined by: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+Sqrt%5Ba%5E2+%2B+b%5E2+%2B+c%5E2+%2B+d%5E2%5D

Comment: Thanks, Brent! I know that this would be one solution but I was sure that there would be a more elegant way in using a closed form expression (i.e. not to tare the Quaternion, which is the result of another expression, apart..)